# html email padding-right issue on Mail client Mac

Tags: macos, padding, html-email

I've got a problem getting my html email to render properly on Mac Mail client. Basically a white strip ~20px wide appears on the right hand side of the display.

This is a html I'm using:

```
<div style="padding:30px !important; height: 60px; border-bottom: 10px solid #07d7ed;">
  <div style="width:100%">
      <div style="float:left">Logo</div>
      <div style="float:right">Some Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas, why this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div`s are not supported everywhere and often come with their own styling. Try using a table instead:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">


            <table width="48%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
            <!--Use less than 50% width to account for outlook which adds space to floated tables -->

                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">Logo</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table width="48%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right">
            <!--Use align instead of float to account for older browsers and outlook which don't handle floats correctly-->
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">sometext</td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Try this and see if it fixes your problem. If not, see if you can post a screenshot.

Comment: Glad to help :) Can you accept the answer as correct if it worked for you?